# Can I place a pdf on the same page as my Sections Title?

Tags: formatting, pdf, pdfpages

When i use `\includepdf` to get documents into my chapters, it always opens on a new page.
Can i use a command, so that it's displayed directly under the sections name?

I tried this:

```
\section*{pdf-file}
\includepdf[pages1-2],scale=0.8,nup=2x1]{MyFile.pdf}
```

scale doesnt matter, it stays on new page even if it would fit the page before.

nup displays the two Pages next to each other so it shouldnt interfere.

Comment: use `\includegraphics`, `\includepdf` is just for including one or more complete pages.

Comment: But i want to include a pdf-file with 2 pages and i thought \includegraphics only worked for the first page of a .pdf

Comment: no you can use `page=2` with `\includegraphics` If you want 2 pages 2-up then do that first with a pdf2pdf transformation or simply use `\includegraphics[page=1]{..}\includegraphics[page=2]{..}` to put the two pages side by side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\section*{pdf-file}

\includegraphics[page=1, scale=..]{..}\hfill\includegraphics[page=2,scale=..]{..}
```

Should put the two pages side by side under the heading.